# Create a table of stepwise values with incomplete data

Tags: excel, graph

I'm having trouble getting my head around this one.

I have a table of values that have missing lookups.

```
Price   Company 1   Company 2   Company 3
$100        5           -           1
$200        2           9           -
$300        6           -           -
$400        -           2           1
$500        4           -           -
```

I want to fill out these missing entries with values from an adjacent cell so I can still graph them in a stepwise manner.

```
Price   Company 1   Company 2   Company 3
$100        5         **9**         1
$200        2           9         **1**
$300        6         **9**       **1**
$400      **6**         2           1
$500        4         **2**       **1**
```

The logic would be to take the value from rows above, and if no possible rows above contain values, to then take the next possible value from rows below. The example above illustrates this. The position of the numbers matter more than the actual value of the numbers in determining what to fill the cell with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
Sub Stepwise()
    'get the worksheet
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        'get the block of data radiating out from A1
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            'shift off the header row and right one column
            With .Cells.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(1, 1)

                'get rid of hyphens
                .Replace what:=Chr(45), replacement:=vbNullString, lookat:=xlWhole
                'optional - get rid of any non-numeric values
                On Error Resume Next
                .Value = .Value2
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) = vbNullString
                On Error GoTo 0

                'shift one more row down - same number of columns
                With .Cells.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                    'make sure there are blank cells
                    If Application.Count(.Cells) < .Cells.Count Then
                        'get the blank cells
                        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                            .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
                        End With
                        .Value = .Value2
                    End If
                End With

                'shorten by one row - same number of columns
                With .Cells.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
                    'make sure there are blank cells
                    If Application.Count(.Cells) < .Cells.Count Then
                        'get the blank cells
                        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                            .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C"
                        End With
                    End If
                    .Value = .Value
                End With

            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

If the logic doesn't hold for larger gaps then attempt modification(s) and come back for help if you get stuck.

[image: Stepwise_sample_data_before]    [image: Stepwise_sample_data_after]
                <sup>Sample data before Stepwise</sup>                                <sup>Sample data after Stepwise</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped. I'm getting a runtime error so I'm not really able to work out the code's functionality (I'm a novice with VBA).

No Cells were found - Line of code:  With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

Comment: Does the formula not work with formulas in the cells? I converted to values and it works

Comment: Yes, formulas in the cells would have to be dealt with differently. See my edit above for conversion to values and all non-numeric data replacement.

Comment: I changed the code to first copy the data elsewhere as replacing the lookups would be a problem in the long run but it works perfectly now. Cheers!